# AIF service operation that returns a table object

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, aif

what is the code of writing operation code that return table object records ( ex: creating a function that return customer information ).
this function will be consume from my application during web service.

```
[SysEntryPointAttribute(true),
AifCollectionTypeAttribute('return', Types::String)]
public MyCustTable testMethod()
{
   CustTable       custTable;
   List list = new List(Types::String);
   MyCustTable temp;
   while select * from custTable
   {

       temp.Name = custTable.name();
       temp.AccountNum = custTable.AccountNum;
   }

   return temp;

//this is not working find, i wan to return some information related to customer like name, phone, 

}
```

this function will be consume from my project using c#

Comment: Could you elaborate on what input parameters you function could have?
Odds are that the function already exists, see `CustTable::find` method.

Comment: I create a function that have no parameters. just return all customers records. in my application i can show the return data in my web application.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: the function in the top return table object but i can not consume it in my application,
I want a function that return list of customer ( name, phone , accountNum)

Comment: Use `findKeys` then `find` actions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return the record directly, you have to use a specific interface.

[AIF service classes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa606696.aspx) usually have these [operations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa864923.aspx):

- create - inputs: Document object - output: AifEntityKeyList - Takes a document object, creates records in the database, and returns a list of the IDs for the new records.
- delete - AifEntityKeyList - Nothing - Takes one or more IDs and deletes the specified records from the database.
- [find](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa844112.aspx) - AifQueryCriteria - Document object
  Takes criteria, queries the database for matching records, and returns them in a document object.
- findKeys - AifQueryCriteria - AifEntityKeyList - Takes criteria, queries the database for matching records, and returns a list of corresponding IDs for those records.
- read - AifEntityKeyList - Document object - Takes one or more IDs, reads the records from the database, and returns the records.
- update - AifEntityKeyList and document object - Nothing - Takes one or more IDs and the data that corresponds to those IDs, and then updates the database. For more information, see Updating Data With AIF.
- getKeys - AifDocumentPaging - AifEntityKeyList - Retrieves the keys for documents based on a document filter. For more information, see Configure processing options.
- getChangedKeys - AifDocumentPaging, changedDateTime - AifEntityKeyList
  Retrieves the keys for documents based on a document filter and a date that is passed in. For more information, see Configuring AIF for change tracking.

See how to create an [AIF document service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa856656.aspx).
The service class methods can be created [using a wizard](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa609947.aspx).

Comment: can write the code of a function that return the list of customer ex:( name, phone )

Comment: Yes, you may (mis)use the `AifEntityKeyList` to provide more fields.